# How to receive a request from HTML and process it on my view and model side

Tags: python, html, django, oracle

I'm new on sofware dev, please be pacient.
I'm trying to receive a request from my html code and get the shift Code value, this can be Shift1, Shift2 or Shift3.

I'm using read-only oracle db, that's why i'm using raw query.
Basically, I want to filter my table results in html code, through the "Shift" result according the user selection, now I'm showing the all shifts results, how to filter it?

Please, tell me how to do it on my views.py and models.py

Html code:

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-secondary" id="menu-toggle"><< Menu</a>
            <h4 align="right" >{{ date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }} </h4>

            <h1>SMD/PBA System Management</h1>              

                <div class="container-fluid">


                Select the shift
               <form action="{ %url 'show_list' %}" method="post">
                  <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-auto my-1">

                      <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" name="shift">
                        <option selected>Shift 1</option>
                        <option value="1">Shift 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Shift 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Shift 3</option>
                        <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
                      </select>
                     </div>
                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
                   </div>
                </form>

                <br>


                <h4>Retest IM</h4>
                    <table align="left" border="2" class="table table-dark">
                     <tr bgcolor="#0080ff">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center">Shift</td>
                        <td align="center">Line</td>
                        <td align="center">Model</td>
                        <td align="center">Insp QTY</td>
                        <td align="center">Retest QTY</td>
                        <td align="center">Index PPM</td>

                        {% for instance in query %}
                                {% if instance.DEF_INDEX_PPM > 5000 %}
                                <tr bgcolor="#ff4d4d">
                                {% else %}
                                <tr>
                                {% endif %}
                                    <td align="center">{{ instance.WORK_YMD }} </td>
                                    <td align="center">{{ instance.SHIFT_CODE }} </td>
                                    <td align="center">{{ instance.LINE_NM }} </td>
                                    <td align="center">{{ instance.MODEL_NM }} </td>
                                    <td align="center">{{ instance.SMD_INSP_QTY }} </td>
                                    <td align="center">{{ instance.SMD_RETEST_DEFT_QTY }} </td>
                                    <td align="center">{{ instance.DEF_INDEX_PPM|floatformat:0 }} </td>
                                </tr>

                        {% endfor %}


                     </tr>
                </table>
                <h4>Retest CE</h4>
                <table align="left" border="2" class="table table-dark">
                     <tr bgcolor="#0080ff">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center">Shift</td>
                        <td align="center">Line</td>
                        <td align="center">Model</td>
                        <td align="center">Insp QTY</td>
                        <td align="center">Retest QTY</td>
                        <td align="center">Index PPM</td>>


                        {% for instance in query2 %}
                               {% if instance.DEF_INDEX_PPM > 5000 %}
                                <tr bgcolor="#ff4d4d">
                                {% else %}
                                <tr>
                                {% endif %}
                                     <td align="center">{{ instance.WORK_YMD }} </td>
                                     <td align="center">{{ instance.SHIFT_CODE }} </td>
                                     <td align="center">{{ instance.LINE_NM }} </td>
                                     <td align="center">{{ instance.MODEL_NM }} </td>
                                     <td align="center">{{ instance.PBA_INSP_QTY }} </td>
                                     <td align="center">{{ instance.PBA_RETEST_DEFT_QTY }} </td>
                                     <td align="center">{{ instance.DEF_INDEX_PPM|floatformat:0 }} </td>

                                </tr>

                        {% endfor %}
                     </tr>
                </table>

                </div>



        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
```

Views.py code:

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader

from .models import my_custom_sql2


# Create your views here.
def show_list(request):

    query2 = my_custom_sql2(self='my_custom_sql2')

    myDate = datetime.now()

    return render(request, 'monitoring.html', {'query2': query2, 'date': myDate})
```

models.py Code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import connection


# Create your models here.
def dictfetchall(cursor):
"Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
desc = cursor.description
return [
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
]




def my_custom_sql2(self):
with connection.cursor()as cursor:
import time
date = time.strftime('%Y%m%d')

            cursor.execute("""
                   select  A.WORK_YMD,
                           A.SHIFT_CODE,
                           --A.LINE_CODE,
                           B.LINE_NM,
                           A.MODEL_NM,
                           A.PBA_INSP_QTY,                          
                           A.PBA_RETEST_DEFT_QTY,                           
                          (A.PBA_RETEST_DEFT_QTY / A.PBA_INSP_QTY * 1000000) 
AS DEF_INDEX_PPM
                                                
                    from TBS_QM_TOTAL_PROC_DEFT A, TBM_MD_LINE B  
                    
                    where  
                           A.WORK_YMD = %s  
                           AND A.LINE_CODE = B.LINE_CODE                                  
                           AND A.PBA_INSP_QTY > 0 
                           --AND A.SHIFT_CODE                            
                          ORDER BY DEF_INDEX_PPM DESC, B.LINE_NM ASC
                    """, [date])
    row = dictfetchall(cursor)

    cursor.close()
    return row
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import show_list


urlpatterns = [
path('list/', show_list, name="show_list"),
]
```

[Html screen:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TssjZ.jpg)

Comment: It's great to start developing using your own use case, but I'd really advise you to take a couple of days to do the full [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/) in order to understand how to handle forms and write views that can handle both GET and POST requests to display your initial form and process the data submitted by the form.

Comment: I agree, I'll follow your advice to implement it throgh the right way, But I'd like to find a implement this dashboard firstly, Then I'll improve it. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you want to return the value checked by the user from the form; to do that you need to work with Django Forms. For more details read the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/

Comment: Thank you for your feed back, I was taking a looking on the django tutoria as you recommended, but is it possible even for raw query in only read database? I didn't find a way to do it